# GLSL extracting modelmatrix from modelviewmatrix and viewmatrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl

since in GLSL the modelmatrix is not available, i was wondering if it is possible to get it programatically from the gl_ModelViewMatrix and the "viewmatrix" which i would pass as a uniform?

if yes, how?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the model matrix by multiplying the modelview matrix with the inverse of your view matrix.

gl_ModelViewMatrix * myViewMatrixInverse

Comment: thanks, but that means that i have to calculate the inverse of the viewmatrix on the clientside and pass it as a uniform, right?

Comment: @matt: afaik there is no built-in function to do a matrix inverse in glsl or opengl. so you have to code your own in either the clientside or the shader, the decision is up to you.

Comment: thank you! and the viewmatrix is the one i get with glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX , ...);
immediately after the gluLookAt(), right?