# Custom point lights in world space (LWJGL / GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, lighting

I'm trying to implement custom lights in world space (I know, it is suggested to do it in view space, but I have my reasons) using LWJGL and GLSL into a little game I'm programming. To do so I need the vertex positions in world space in the shader. I know, that I can calculate them as modelMatrix*gl_Vertex in the Vertex Shader. Since the modelMatrix is not accessible in the shader, I calculate it (as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147280/glsl-extracting-modelmatrix-from-modelviewmatrix-and-viewmatrix)) by multiplying the ModelViewMatrix with the inverse of the viewMatrix.

Vertex shader code:

```
uniform mat4 inverseViewMatrix;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 worldCoord;

normal = normalize(vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix *inverseViewMatrix * vec4(gl_Normal,0.0)));
worldCoord = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix *inverseViewMatrix *gl_Vertex);            //coordinates in world space?
```

The light is then calculated per pixel in the fragment shader:

```
uniform vec4 lights[30];    //lightPositions...
uniform vec4 lightCol[30];    //...& lightColors passed from the Java-Code
uniform int noOfLights;

varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 worldCoord;

for(int i = 0; i < noOfLights; i++){

    vec3 lightPos = (lights[i]).xyz;     // lights[i].w does contain data if parallel or point light

    if(lights[i].w == 1.0){     //parallel lights (working fine)


        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos);            //light direction
        float NdotL = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

        brightness += (NdotL*lightCol[i].xyz);          //lightCol[i].xyz does contain the color of the light

    }

    else{                       //point lights (not working)

        vec3 lightPosRelative = lightPos - worldCoord;  //Vector from Vertex to point light

        float dist = length(lightPosRelative);

        if(dist < lightCol[i].w){           //lightCol[i].w is the radius of the point light

            vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPosRelative);    //light direction to point light
            float NdotL = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

            float distVal = pow(1.0-(dist/lightCol[i].w), 2.0);     //light attenuation with distance
            distVal = clamp(distVal, 0.0, 1.0);

            brightness += (NdotL*lightCol[i].xyz)*distVal;          //lightCol[i].xyz does contain the color of the light
        }
    }

}

[... brightness is then multiplied with the vertexColor...]
```

The inverse of the view matrix is passed to the shader from the Java side of the code. It is calculated after the camera has been positioned using glRotatef(...) and glTranslatef(...).

```
Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();       
Matrix4f inverseViewMatrix = new Matrix4f();                
viewBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

viewBuffer.rewind();
glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, viewBuffer);
viewMatrix = (Matrix4f) viewMatrix.load(modelBuffer);

Matrix4f.invert(viewMatrix, inverseViewMatrix);
```

The result looks fine for the parallel lights. The calculation of the normals therefore seems to be correct.

The point lights, however, do only affect the terrain (which is never rotated nor translated) and not other objects (which are translated and rotated).
Somethings seems to be wrong with the calculation of worldCoord for the objects (I can see that by displaying worldCoord instead of the brightness).

Any suggestions what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You have ``lightPos`` as a uniform and as a local variable.

Comment: Oops. I renamed some variables to make the code easier to read. Seems like I've messed this up. Fixed.